# octave not reading anaconda python on linux

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, octave, conda

I installed octave on `ubuntu 16.04`, installed the symbolic package and loaded it to octave

tried to create a symbolic character

got this error:

> ```
> syms x OctSymPy v2.6.0: this is free software without warranty, see
> source. Initializing communication with SymPy using a popen2() pipe.
> error: SymPy is installed but is too old (sympy-0.7.6.1 found, 1.0
> required) error: called from
>     assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 44 column 7
>     python_ipc_popen2 at line 78 column 5
>     python_ipc_driver at line 59 column 13
>     python_cmd at line 164 column 9
>     valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
>     assumptions at line 82 column 7
>     syms at line 97 column 13
> ```

updated sympy using conda `version 1.1`

Comment: This does not seem right. Are you sure you upgraded sympy (there wasn't any error messages?). Try installing it again possibly by some other way

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same problem. I could import SymPy in my system's Python prompt because I had it installed by Anaconda, but Octave wouldn't recognize it. What I did was I set the `PYTHON` environment variable in Octave to the Anaconda `bin` directory. That is, I did

```
which python #in terminal: which gives /path/to/anaconda/bin/python
```

and then

```
setenv PYTHON /path/to/anaconda/bin/python
sympref reset
```

All thanks go to [this guy](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Solution-Point-octave-to-anaconda-python-Mac-td4689111.html).